# Pointers in C resulting in unknown random char

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have some C code to print a string char array twice.

```
Code:

char* twice(char *s) {
   int size=strlen(s),i=0;
   int length=size*2;
   char check = s[size-1];
   char* s2 = malloc(length * sizeof(char));
   char* reset = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
   memcpy(reset, s, size * sizeof(char));

   while (i<length) {
      printf("%s\n", s);
      s2[i] = *s;
      if(s2[i] == check && i == size-1){
        s = reset;
      }else s++;
      i++;
    }
   return s2;
}

int main(){
    char s[] = "hello1234";
    printf("%s\n", twice(s));

    return 0;
}


Output:

hello1234
ello1234
llo1234
lo1234
o1234
1234
234
34
4
hello1234
ello1234
llo1234
lo1234
o1234
1234
234
34
4
hello1234hello1234Ms?
```

The inputted string is `hello1234` and i am printing out each pointer to show that it correctly runs through the string twice. But for some reason the answer includes `Ms?` resulting in `hello1234hello1234Ms?` why is that?

Comment: `size=strlen(s)`. You are not copying the NUL terminator from the original string `s` to the `reset` string. You need to copy `strlen(s)+1` to include the NUL terminator. Or better still, don't copy at all. Just use a pointer, `char *reset = s;`

Comment: Return of strlen() is size_t.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, strings are terminated with a special character with the value `'\0'`.

`memcpy()` works with memory, it is not specific to strings. And so it does not copy the terminator since you didn't give it a length that includes the terminator. (`strlen()` does not include the terminator.)

When `printf()` doesn't find the terminator, it just keeps printing whatever is in memory. The additional characters are just random and will be different on different set ups.